# How do i share my asp.net code with my team without using a server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working on asp.net project using `VS2010`.

I want to share my project code with one of my team member who is at some other geographical location but as we don't have a server we are not able to use TFS.

Can anyone tell me how can I share my code?

Or somehow can I use TFS on my local machine (or any other VS extension) and share it with him?

So that by using internet we can share our code with each other with help of any tool like TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would however recommend that you use [TFS Preview](http://tfspreview.com/) to achieve this as it is free and provided all of the same goodies as having a local server without the need to run even a local server.

However if you must have local storage you can use [TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express). It is free and will run just fine on your local computer. All you then need to do is expose your computer over HTTP and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using distributed version control such as [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com)? I do not know whether these systems can run serverless, nor do I have personal experience using them, but I've heard good things about the concept.